# how to create backbone view with more link button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to create a backbone view which has more button in it. Please check the below image

[image: backbone view]
Those button's are generated from different response's, for each button one response will be there, so dynamically I am creating the button view and appending it.

If the more buttons ( 4,5 etc) are there i need to show a "more" button, so that if the user clicks "more" button I need to expand and show all the buttons.

How we can handle this case? I have tried backbone collection

Comment: Hi, please share the sample code, sample response etc. *"dynamically i am creating the button view and appending it"* - wondering why each tiny button is a `Backbone.View`, anyway have you tried any means of hiding them via adding a `hide` class or similar when these views are created, which is later removed onclick of the view more button..?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , these buttons represents some information , user can delete button , modify content inside those button. response will contain information to show on those buttons. the issue i am facing is how we will show "more" button always on right corner? if we click more button it should expand and show the remaining buttons not like hide & show

Comment: more button is not part of response right..? why cant you put the more button in a separate container (`<div>` etc) which is pushed to right..? this seems like a css issue

Comment: Thanks for the input, yeah more button is not part of response. I will try creating new <div>

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/u9y574y8/

```
ExpandableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    itemTemplate: _.template('<button name="<%=name%>" id="<%=name%>" value="<%=name%>"><%=name%></button>'),
    id: 'expand',
    events: {
        'click #more': 'more'
    },
    initialize: function(opt) {
        // attach to the main body
        $(opt['main']).append(this.el)

        this.counter = 3;
        this.render();
    },
    more: function() {
        this.counter += 3;
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < this.counter; i++) {
            $(this.el).append(this.itemTemplate({name: i}));
        }
        $(this.el).append(this.itemTemplate({name: 'more'}));

        return this;
    }
});

var search_view = new ExpandableView({ main: $('body') });
```